# Entity framework. Reloading local data

Tags: c#, wpf, entity-framework, data-binding

I have a control in WPF app that binds to this property

```
public ObservableCollection<Entity.Account> Accounts
{
    get
    {
        _context.Accounts.Load();
        return _context.Accounts.Local;
    }
}
```

I expected that every time control reaches for data, local collection gets reloaded from scratch from database because of Load() method, but apparently I was wrong.

So I have two questions: what exactly Load() does if it's not loading entities from context to local? And how can i populate local collection by other means but Load()?

---

**More details:**

First here's how it's bound:`<TextBox Text="{Binding Name}"/>`
and in code-behind `DataContext = _viewmodel.Accounts;`

This *Accounts* property is exactly the one I wrote above. And the *Name* propery it binds to is a part of Account entity.

If you edit the account's name and won't call EntityContext.SaveChanges() it will change in local collection but won't change in database and calling Load() method won't refresh local collection. It only refreshes when program restarts (when context is created anew)

Answer (score 1):

> what exactly Load() does if it's not loading entities from context to local?

The *Load* is an extension method on IQueryable that enumerates the results of the query. This is equivalent to calling ToList without actually creating the list.
[read here from MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.dbextensions.load(v=vs.103).aspx)

> how can i populate local collection by other means but Load()?

Do you mean refresh? if yes then you can use the *Reload*
which will reload the entity from the database overwriting any property values with values from the database. 
 as:

```
         foreach (var entity in _context.ChangeTracker.Entries())
         {
           entity.Reload();
         }
```

[Reload Method MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.infrastructure.dbentityentry.reload%28v=vs.113%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

Comment: Thanks for answer and the links. I've seen that article and a couple of others, unfortunatelly it doesn't really help to understand how it populates Local property of Context. And the Reload() method belongs to DbEntityEntry class and either it's me doing it wrong or you can't use that method on ObservableCollection<> object.

Comment: yeah, solved it, now I have question is the information you wanna refresh nested ?